# Interesting c++ [inter] process synchronization

Tags: c++11, boost, process, signals, semaphore

Say you have n processes, where n is dynamic. They can be running on the same machine or across a network. Imagine that each process is given on the command line a [csv] file which is to be read. The contents of each line is pushed onto an std::vector of tuple. Each of the files that correspond to each process is of different size. The different machines can be of different speeds not to mention their disks could be vastly faster/slower than each other. Also, the files contains timestamps. The first phase reads the entire file. When processing the lines in memory, each process can be told to be in ready state when the line with a certain timestamp is reached or immediately after reading the entire file. Notice that it can take each process a completely different amount of time to get to the "right line." A process cannot start the next phase until it is signaled to start, which by this problem means all others are also ready to start.

My question is, what is the best way to have all the processes synchronize with each other so that when each process has read the file and has read to it's requested time, they are all signaled so that all processes are ready to start the next phase of operation. However, they are not polling for all other process to go to ready state. Instead hey are sync wait or some other mechanism. Once they **all** say they are ready to go, they all will start within say 50 microseconds of each other (not worried about network time synchronization for now I am just talking about network jitter).

A simple example of two processes signaling each other [possibly with an additional master process that handles all synchronization as an intermediary] on some condition across a network in c++11 [with/without boost] is useful. If there is a master process that handles the synchronization, it doesn't matter what language it is written in as long as it runs on linux. But the "slave" processes have to be in c++11.

Comment: All slaves could push a "ready" message on a message queue. A master process that knows how many slaves there is could monitor this queue and wait for all slaves to send a ready state before issuing a request on all of them, probably via a network broadcast to account the the required jitter variance.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought of doing. Each process on startup pushes it pid to a [remote] queue. The queue remembers all the processes that registered with it. Then when a process is in ready mode, it pops the same ID. When the queue is empty, they are all signaled by the queue. It is the details that I am interested in.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't rely on the PID since it machine agnostic. You would need some machine ID on top of the process ID. As for the details, there are dozens of message queue systems available like MSQS, ASQS, IronMQ, etc. You should evaluate their feature set and pick which one is the best for you. That choice will influence the implementation specifics of your design. You can come back on SO once you have more specific questions.

Comment: Right, I meant an IP address + pid etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol to synchronize clocks on all machines.
2. Create a master process, run as UDP client.
3. All slave processes run as UDP servers.
4. A slave process sends "ready" packet to the master.
5. Once all slaves are ready, the master sends out a UDP broadcast message to all slaves. The message contains a future (not too far, just enough to overcome the network delay) time stamp for all slaves to start the next sync operation at that time point.